# How can I assign string copied to clipboard after selenium button click to a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to make string copied from selenium button click.
The site provides a button-like div tag.
If I click the tag, then an URL copied to my clipboard.
And I want that URL into string.
Can Selenium make that possible?
here's some code:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
...
_driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
_driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

_options = new ChromeOptions();
_options.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
_options.AddArgument(String.Format("user-data-dir={0}", profilePath));
// _options.AddArgument("headless");
// headless cannot usable in WPF... why?

_driver = new ChromeDriver(_driverService, _options);

_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("The site that provides what I want");
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

var element = _driver.FindElementByXPath("The tag's xpath");
element.Click();
// I think this copy an url probably, or not.
// what should I do from here? to assign that url to a string variable?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make string"?

Comment: I mean to declare a string. Sorry, I'm not living in an English country, and English is not my primary language.

Comment: Ok. I think I know what you mean. There is a copy-to-clipboard button. After clicking the button (which copies a link to the clipboard) how do you assign that to a string variable in C#?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I updated your question title to reflect your last comment, if that's ok.

Comment: That's ok because I'm not good at English.. so, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selenium to create a text area element, and paste the contents of the clipboard. Then extract the value from the text area.

```
// After clicking the copy-to-clipboard button

var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

var textarea = (IWebElement)executor.ExecuteScript("document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'));");

var action = new Actions(driver)
    .MoveToElement(textarea)
    .Click()
    .KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
    .SendKeys("v")
    .KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control);
    
action.Perform();

var url = textarea.GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks. but an error says "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed."

Comment: Oops! Slight mistake in the JavaScript. I updated my answer. Should be document.**body**.appendChild(...) - try again.

Comment: I tried some times, Firstly, 'executor' does not have ExecuteJavaScript(), so I tried ExecuteScript() instead of ExecuteJavaScript(). But It made textarea successfully. Secondly, 'action' keeps made an error "MoveToElement cannot move to a null element with no offset." even in a new tab page (google.com), under Thread.Sleep() and action.Build().Perform();

Comment: @UfLix: I'll need to review this in the morning. I'm trying to type on a mobile phone. Makes writing code a little difficult.

Comment: OK. Thanks for helping. I will research more to complete this problem :-D

Comment: well.., I got the answer. after copy the link, then open a new tab because some web pages didn't allow making textarea.

Comment: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var textarea = executor.ExecuteScript("document.body.appendChild...);
// Find the textarea element because, for some reason, selenium senses that textarea element is not visible
var text = driver.FindElementByXPath("textarea's xpath");
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", text);
string URL = (string)executor.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1].value"););`